# How to check if a HTTP address is responding without throwing exceptions?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, httpwebrequest, http-status-code-404, system.net.webexception

WebClient and HttpWebRequest throw WebException when connecting to an unavailable address. I've seen some techniques that use BeginGetResponse that avoid throwing exceptions in this case. But they rely heavily on the Async keyword. Is there any way to check a HTTP service without throwing exceptions and using only .NET 3.5?

Comment: what's the problem with exceptions? are you handling them? try catch...

Comment: what you want to do when error occur if you don't want to handle exception?

Comment: If you develop a program mostly exception-free it's easier to debug. I maintain a big application and this is the only exception thrown when everything is in normal conditions.

I would like to HttpWebRequest to return the status code so I could decide for myself what to do with it.